# updating source index for current snapshot in Castalia

Tags: omnet++

I am working on adding more than two snapshots in my physical process.

in the customizable physical process when the current snapshot is updated the time is compared before updating. 
then it is checked if the end is reached as following:

```
if(sources_snapshots[i][source_index[i]+1].time == -1)
 source_index[i] = -2;
```

it seems like if the time of the next snapshot is -1 the end is reached. but why is it so?
if I am defining the time of each snapshot, do I have to define the time of last snapshot as -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not have to define the time of your last snapshot as -1. Just follow the example that the manual provides and you should be ok.

The values of -1 and -2 that you see in the code are used as internal markers so that the code knows where to stop. You do not set these.

Remember that you can define up to 10 snapshots for one source, and you can have up to 5 sources in total. If you want more snapshots per source, you can change the following parameter in you physical process: `max_num_snapshots`

Comment: even if i am creating my own physical process?

Comment: Since you mentioned "snapshots", I assumed you meant defining your own **CustomizablePhysicalProcess** (meaning that you use they already implemented phy process, and you just define your own sources in your ini file). If you are talking about creating a completely new module (meaning writing new code) then this question is not relevant. You can implement your own module however you want.